# How can I change chunk_size for Resumable Upload?

Tags: google-api-ruby-client

I need upload some big files(about 1Gb) into google drive.
I using google-api-client(ruby) version 0.5.0:

```
media = Google::APIClient::UploadIO.new(file_name, mimeType, original_name)
result = client.execute!(
        :api_method => client.service.files.insert,
        :body_object => file,
        :media => media,
        :parameters => {
            'uploadType' => 'resumable',
            'alt' => 'json'})
```

I expected that my client split big file on parts and upload these parts on drive.
But I see in logs, that client sending only ONE BIG chunk to drive.
Here is small log example:

> Content-Length: "132447559"
>   Content-Range: "bytes 0-132447558/132447559"

How can I upload big files by chunks with google-api-client?

Answer (score 0):

The intended usage is to try and upload the file in a single chunk. Overall, it's more efficient/faster that way. But there are cases where chunking is preferable, so if you need to chunk the upload for whatever reason, just set the chunk_size property:

```
media = Google::APIClient::UploadIO.new(file_name, mimeType, original_name)
media.chunk_size = 1000000 # 1mb chunks
result = client.execute!(....)
```

Comment: Seems like this is no longer true in v0.6.3 of the API client. `Google::APIClient::UploadIO` appears to not define `chunk_size=`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the API version 0.7.1, even though I know we're supposed to be using version 0.9 now, because the older version matches the Ruby examples on Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/ruby).

I had to do resort to uploading in chunks because I was getting errors in httpclient library complaining about the file size being too large to convert to integer!

Unfortunately, using @stevebazyl did not work for me as it only uploads the first chunk and then throws a `TransmissionError`. This seems to be in the google-api-ruby-client code, specifically, `Google::APIClient` class in the `execute!` method. It doesn't seem to be handling an HTTP status of 308, which is what a resumable upload returns when it needs the next chunk. I did this to the code:

```ruby
when 200...300, 308
  result
```

(See [api_client.rb](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/google-api-client-0.7.1/lib/google/api_client.rb#L601))

And use the `#send_all` method in the `ResumableUpload` class just like the sample code in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/ruby#upload_a_video) and it worked for me. So in addition to @stevebazyl code, I have:

```ruby
media = Google::APIClient::UploadIO.new(opts[:file], 'video/*')
media.chunk_size = 499200000

videos_insert_response = client.execute!(
  :api_method => youtube.videos.insert,
  :body_object => body,
  :media => media,
  :parameters => {
    :uploadType => 'resumable',
    :part => body.keys.join(',')
  }
)

videos_insert_response.resumable_upload.send_all(client)
```